# Get Numerical Value in Bit Vector in Z3 in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to get the numerical value from a bit vector after solving it using the following API

```
u64 value; 
Z3_get_numeral_uint64(myContext(),myBitVector,&value);
```

Howerver the results in `value` are in decimal form , How can I return it in Hexadecimal form ?

Comment: what do you mean that `value` is in decimal form? It is an integral type, not a string. I think that you can print it in hex using `printf("0x%" PRIx64 "\n", value);` (including `inttypes.h`)...

Comment: I do not want to print it , I am post processing this value so I want it in Hex format

Comment: You mean in a string? In that case, just use `snprintf` instead of `printf`.

Comment: Again !  , I an not PRINTING , I am using the value in post processing and it must be hexadecimal  !

Comment: In that case, what is the difference between decimal and hexadecimal? The value of a number is completely independent of its base. Perhaps I am missing something? Could you elaborate on what you mean by "hexadecimal form"?

Comment: The returned value is decimal , although the equation solution is given in hexadecimal.
any way , I need to use this value to search in a map of hexadecimals not decimal (base 10)

Comment: There seems to be some confusion about the underlying representation of numbers here. The returned value is a `u64`, not a string, not in hex, and not a decimal. If your map uses strings (of hex-formatted numbers) as keys or values, you need to convert the `u64` to a string. If it uses any other representation, you need to use a different conversion. If it happens to use `u64`s, you don't have to do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `std::hex` to get the value in hex form:

```
std::stringstream s;

s << std::hex << value;

std::cout << s.str();
```

Answer (score 0):

This really has nothing to do with z3. A hexadecimal (or any other base) representation is just how you write things down in characters as a string. The underlying bit-pattern, represented as a series of bits, is always just that: a bunch of 0's and 1's.

To post-process, you most likely mean take the "hex" representation of the number as a string and do something with it. In C, you can use `sprintf` to get your number printed in various bases in a string and do what you want with them. Something like:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  uint64_t i = 253;

  char buf[100];   /* Make sure this is large enough! */

  sprintf(buf, "%"PRIx64, i);

  // Now post-process in any way you want.
  // I'll just add -- HELLO to the end.
  strcat(buf, " -- HELLO");

  printf("%s\n", buf);

  return 0;
}
```

When I run this, I get:

```
$ make a
c++     a.cpp   -o a
$ ./a
fd -- HELLO
```

this is because `253` written in hex is `fd`, and then I added some other string to it, i.e., post-processed it.

Again, it's important to emphasize that this has nothing to do with z3, and numbers in different bases is merely how you represent them in ASCII. Internally, it's just a bunch of bits and it doesn't make sense to talk about whether it's hex or octal or decimal or any other base.